# Why do people use `Module.send(:prepend, …)`?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-2.0

I'm learning how to use `Module.prepend` instead of `alias_method_chain` in my Ruby code, and I've noticed that some people use `send` to call it ([example](http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/rails-5-module-number-prepend-and-the-end-of-alias-method-chain/)):

```
ActionView::TemplateRenderer.send(:prepend,
    ActionViewTemplateRendererWithCurrentTemplate)
```

While others call it directly ([example](https://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/module-prepend-a-super-story)):

```
ActionView::TemplateRenderer.prepend(ActionViewTemplateRendererWithCurrentTemplate)
```

And, although I haven't seen anyone use this style, I suspect from the documentation that you could even write this in the module you're prepending from:

```
module ActionViewTemplateRendererWithCurrentTemplate
    # Methods you're overriding go here

    prepend_features ActionView::TemplateRenderer
end
```

Is there some difference between these three styles? Is there a reason to favor one over the others?

Comment: Probably people still write it this way because of 'old habits', since #include and #prepend used to be private methods before Ruby 2.1.

Comment: `prepend_features` is a hook method that is called by `prepend` and generally *not* intended nor designed to be called directly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Module#prepend` was [added](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ruby_2_0_0/NEWS#L112-L116) to **Ruby version `2.0.0`**.

It was originally added as a **private** method, with the intended use case being in the following format:

```
module Foo
  # ...
end

class Bar
  prepend Foo

  # ... The rest of the class definition ...
end
```

However, it soon became apparent that in many cases people wanted to prepend a module to a class without defining any other aspects of the class (in that section of code). Hence, the following pattern became common:

```
Bar.send(:prepend, Foo)
```

In **Ruby version `2.1.0`**, this issue was addressed by [making `Module#prepend` a public method](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_1_0/NEWS#L96) - so you can now simply write this as:

```
Bar.prepend(Foo)
```

However, note that if you are writing a library that is required to support Ruby `2.0.0` (even though [official support ended](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2016/02/24/support-plan-of-ruby-2-0-0-and-2-1/) on 24th Feb 2016), then you must unfortunately stick to the old `.send(:prepend, ...)` approach.

`Module#include` (which has been in the Ruby language since its inception) was also a private method in version `<= 2.0.0`, and was made public in `2.1.0`.

Comment: Thanks for the history! I never realized `include` and `prepend` were made public, and I've been legacy-coding them with `.send` for too long.